# How to choose the best pub?

Tags: micropub

I'm doing a project connected with pubs. Could you please tell me the criterions of the 'natural' British pubs? I would be grateful :)

Comment: Count the number of crooked or missing teeth in the pub.  The higher the number, the better the pub.

Answer (score 1):

**How to choose the best pub?**

To one degree or another this is a personal choice., no matter where the pub is located. However there are three are three general points of criteria that should be observed: **great food, cleanliness, and a awesome atmosphere!**

Of course atmosphere is in the eyes of the beholder, so some looking around may be involved. Great pubs will make you feel at home and should be open to suggestions as to another pub, if one is looking for a particular type of dining and drinking atmosphere that caters to an individual’s different tastes in food, drink or even music (atmosphere). If pubs are not friendly or overly noisy, they are not worthy of being called a pub with a great atmosphere.

[Top factors when choosing a pub to visit - including cleanliness and good food!](https://www.hulldailymail.co.uk/whats-on/food-drink/pub-choices-food-drinks-cleanliness-7132576)